# How do you save user's input as a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a user of my website to be able to type into a text box and have that user's input saved as a link on my site.

**Example**

user is on `mysite.com/a`

```
User: Test
```

Now the user can view "test" from a random link on my site like `mysite.com/a/msg_id=shsu2728jsjwoP8`

I want this saved automatically

I'm hosting my code on GitHub Pages with a custom domain, is this possible?
(I'm also very new to coding)

An HTML or JavaScript answer is preferable.

Comment: `I'm hosting my site on GitHub, is this possible?` are you talking about a `github.io` page? Otherwise you can't host a website on github...`I want this saved automatically` saved where? And what have you tried so far? Please post your code

Comment: Save the input in a database, with a randomly generated key. Then return them a URL that points to a script that takes the key as a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar how would i do that?

Comment: There are many tutorials on using databases from webserver scripts. I have no idea if it's possible with github hosting.

Comment: *I want a user of my website to be able to type into a text box and have that user's input saved as a link on my site.* Trust me, you don't want to do this. You open yourself up to a lot of security concerns.

Comment: You can use **SQLite** for example and generate a json file that can be committed/updated in GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise you can host on https://firebase.google.com/ and you can use it as a Realtime data storage.